# Vim with YouCompleteMe , Error

Tags: vim, plugins

I followed [this](http://www.alexeyshmalko.com/2014/youcompleteme-ultimate-autocomplete-plugin-for-vim/) guide to set up YouCompleteMe for my server. This is what i did:

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle
git clone https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe.git
cd YouCompleteMe
git submodule update --init --recursive
./install.sh --clang-completer
```

followed by adding this to my vimrc :

> let g:ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf = "~/.vim/.ycm_extra_conf.py"

and my .ycm_extra_conf.py has https://github.com/rasendubi/dotfiles/blob/master/.vim/.ycm_extra_conf.py

When I start my vim, its really slow to start up (takes about 30 seconds), then I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/stu9/s15/hxg7013/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/requests/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py",
>   line 137, in _new_conn
>       (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)   File "/home/stu9/s15/hxg7013/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/requests/requests/packages/urllib3/util/connection.py",
>   line 91, in create_connection
>       raise err   File "/home/stu9/s15/hxg7013/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/requests/requests/packages/urllib3/util/connection.py",
>   line 81, in create_connection
>       sock.connect(sa) ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused During handling of the above exception, another exception
>   occurred: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/stu9/s15/hxg7013/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/requests/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
>   line 559, in urlopen
>       body=body, headers=headers)   File "/home/stu9/s15/hxg7013/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/requests/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
>   line 353, in _make_request
>       conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1106, in request
>       self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1151, in _send_request
>       self.endheaders(body)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1102, in endheaders
>       self._send_output(message_body)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 934, in _send_output
>       self.send(msg)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 877, in send
>       self.connect()   File "/home/stu9/s15/hxg7013/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/requests/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py",
>   line 162, in connect
>       conn = self._new_conn()   File "/home/stu9/s15/hxg7013/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/requests/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py",
>   line 146, in _new_conn
>       self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e) requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError:
>   : Failed to establish a new connection: [ Errno 111]
>   Connection refused During handling of the above exception, another
>   exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/stu9/s15/hxg7013/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/requests/requests/adapters.py",
>   line 376, in send
>       timeout=timeout   File "/home/stu9/s15/hxg7013/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/requests/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
>   line 609, in urlopen
>       _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])   File "/home/stu9/s15/hxg7013/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/requests/requests/packages/urllib3/util/retry.py",
>   line 273, in increment
>       raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause)) requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError:
>   HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=37001): Max retries exceeded
>   with url: /shutdown (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111]
>   Connection refused',)) During handling of the above exception, another
>   exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "", line 1, in    File
>   "/home/stu9/s15/hxg7013/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/autoload/../python/ycm/youcompleteme.py",
>   line 337, in OnVimLeave
>       self._ShutdownServer()   File "/home/stu9/s15/hxg7013/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/autoload/../python/ycm/youcompleteme.py",
>   line 214, in _ShutdownServer
>
> However, after this, I'm able to use vim fine (its still sluggish, but
>   I'm able to use it).

Comment: Please either post relevant Python code in the question or remove the Python tag.

Comment: sorry , removed it

Comment: It looks like you've posted half the error. You should always post the *full* error.

Comment: i have updated, please take a look